# Gratis personal finance manager

Tags: gratis, finance

I need a personal finance manager (in terms of "budget manager"). I don't need any future predictions or taxes calculations, simply a wallet like application with reports and charts.

I need to create at least 2 bank accounts (manually maintained, so no "online connection" needed here), and some income and expence accounts. I am from India.

I'm looking for software that's free of cost. I usually use Windows, although I can change to Linux if it is worth it. Though I will prefer a web app because I move a lot and I use many computers.

I don't need any fancy reports or charts, the only main report i am interested in are

- account-wise ledger and complete ledger i.e account statements(for Bank accounts, income and expense accounts).
- year opening and closing statements

Also, I will enter everything manually, no need for automation for bank accounts.

Comment: FYI [Desktop application equivalent to Mint.com?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/24753/5656)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Mint](https://www.mint.com/) (Web App/Mobile)

It's a major player in the personal finance area. It offers all the standard features (income/expense tracking) as well as reports.

However, it's primarily geared towards US consumers, so might not be ideal for an Indian user).

**free version available**

## [You Need A Budget](https://www.youneedabudget.com/) (Windows/Mac)

Very popular application that focuses around tracking of your budget.

> YNAB is built to let you easily set aside funds for larger, infrequent bills. $600 car insurance premium due in six months? Budget $100 each month into your 'Car insurance' category and watch the balance grow. When the bill is due, you pay it and everything feels the same.  That is, what used to send you into financial "crisis mode" now doesn't even make you blink.

[image: zzz]
<sub>(source: [youneedabudget.com](https://www.youneedabudget.com/themes/site_themes/default_site/img/budget_interface.jpg))</sub>

**free trial available**

## [Gnucash](http://www.gnucash.org/)

Open source and cross platform

> Designed to be easy to use, yet powerful and flexible, GnuCash allows you to track bank accounts, stocks, income and expenses. As quick and intuitive to use as a checkbook register, it is based on professional accounting principles to ensure balanced books and accurate reports

Comment: Its paid. Right? I need a free one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Mint has a free version. I've updated my answer sorry.

Comment: Thanks, Mint is not supported  for Indian users,I'll check gnucash.

Comment: Checked GnuCash. Its good, but a bit confused, maybe because it is not made for India (or maybe I have a transition problem) anyway thanks.(Although any new suggestions are welcome)

Comment: Warning for future viewers: I loved the look of mint purely for the UX it appears to have. However, it's only really available/tailored to US and Canadian users - when you sign up it asks for a zip code. By all means, submit a request to have your bank/country supported [here](https://www.mint.com/contact-mint) (select "My bank is not in the USA..." under the drop down topics), but until that's resolved I'm going to look for other solutions.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using [Toshl](https://toshl.com/) for a month now and I'm a big fan. It's free, but you can pay to be able to manage more accounts + budgets. However, it's intuitive, easy to use, effective and it's a web app with a perfectly functional free version.

(The monsters can be turned off in the settings as well, if you prefer a more sombre experience).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to GnuCash, which was mentioned earlier, you can also have a look at [ledger](https://www.ledger-cli.org/) and the whole concept of [Plain-Text Accounting](https://plaintextaccounting.org/). The reports are pretty powerful. It does take some getting-used-to. There are several GUI options available in the ecosystem.